# $f: V \rightarrow V$ a linear function such that $f^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ a finite dimensionnal vectorial space and $f: V \rightarrow V$ a linear function such as $f^2=0$. Is the trivial solution the only solution for $f$ ?

Comment: What does $f^2$ mean in a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the matrix $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $A^2 = 0$. Since linear maps correspond to matrices, we can find a counterexample to your claim.

Indeed, the associated linear map is $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(1,0) = (0,0)$, $f(0,1) = (1,0)$ and this satisfies $f^2 = 0.$

Comment: $A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ also works

Comment: Yes, any matrix $A$ with $A^2 = 0, A \neq 0$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be a basis for $V$. Now consider the unique linear map $f : V \to V$ such that
$$
f(v_i) = \begin{cases} 
v_2 & \textrm{if } i=1, \\ 0 & \textrm{if } i=2,\dots,n. 
\end{cases}
$$
Obviously, $f$ is not the zero function, and also, since $f(f(v_j)) = 0$ for any $j$ between $1$ and $n$, $f^2$ is in fact the zero function.